# Flutter Firestore query with startAfter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Flutter (cloud_firestore) and trying to get data from Firestore after document with title `'xxx'`, but it returns 0 results.

```
return Firestore.instance.collection('products')
    .orderBy('title')
    .startAfter([{'title': 'xxx'}
]);
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I properly implement flutter pagination?

Comment: check this thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717407/flutter-firestore-pagination

Answer (score 8):

You should pass a value, not a map:

```
return Firestore.instance.collection('products')
    .orderBy('title')
    .startAfter(['xxx']);
```

The documentation on this is not particularly clear.

Comment: You're supposed to be able to pass in a document so you can paginate correctly even if multiple documents share the same value... I'm beginning to think using Firestore with flutter was a mistake.

Comment: Tyler is correct, their example is pretty clear about this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query

Answer (score 1):

You can pass entire `doc` using `startAfterDocument` method

```
_db
.collection('requirement')
.orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
.startAfterDocument(lastVisible)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. My orderBy is based on {FirstName, LastName & Email}. So, the startAfter should also match these field values. I saved the document in a variable and later made a list with the values of those fields and used as startAfter parameter.

```
static final Query queryBase = userCollectionRef
      .orderBy(FieldNames.FIRST_NAME)
      .orderBy(FieldNames.LAST_NAME)
      .orderBy(FieldNames.EMAIL);

  DocumentSnapshot _lastUser;
  Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getAllUserDocuments({
    bool next,
    int limit = 10,
  }) async {
    List<DocumentSnapshot> _userDocSnaps = [];
    try {
      if (!next) _lastUser = null;
      Query _query = queryBase;
      if (_lastUser != null)
        _query = _query.startAfter([
          _lastUser.data[FieldNames.FIRST_NAME],
          _lastUser.data[FieldNames.LAST_NAME],
          _lastUser.data[FieldNames.EMAIL],
        ]);
      var _userDocsSnap = await _query.limit(limit).getDocuments();
      if (_userDocsSnap != null && _userDocsSnap.documents != null) {
        _userDocSnaps = _userDocsSnap.documents;
        if (_userDocSnaps != null && _userDocSnaps.length >= 1)
          _lastUser = _userDocSnaps[_userDocSnaps.length - 1];
      }
    } catch (err) {
      String errMessage = 'Exception in method _getAllUserDocuments';
      PrintHelper.handlePrint(errMessage, err);
    }
    return _userDocSnaps;
  }
```