# How to paginate in Firestore using flutter_bloc?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-bloc

By learning flutter_bloc and Firestore, I was able to query all data from my database by creating a special method in the DatabaseService class.

```dart
Future<List<EntryModel>> retrieveEntryData(String userDiary) async {
    QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot =
    await _db.collection(userDiary).orderBy("date").get();
    return snapshot.docs
        .map((docSnapshot) => EntryModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(docSnapshot))
        .toList();
  }
```

And it's cool! This works the way I wanted. But! Now I want to learn how to use pagination (or lazy loading if you like).

In the official documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors?hl=en#dart) I found this:

```dart
// Construct query for first 25 cities, ordered by population
final first = db.collection("cities").orderBy("population").limit(25);

first.get().then(
  (documentSnapshots) {
    // Get the last visible document
    final lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.size - 1];

    // Construct a new query starting at this document,
    // get the next 25 cities.
    final next = db
        .collection("cities")
        .orderBy("population")
        .startAfter([lastVisible]).limit(25);

    // Use the query for pagination
    // ...
  },
  onError: (e) => print("Error completing: $e"),
);
```

This allowed me to write a method in my class that returns the first 10 records.

```dart
// Retrieve first 10 entries
  Future<List<EntryModel>> retrieveEntryDataFirst(String userDiary) async {
    QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot =
    await _db.collection(userDiary).orderBy("date").limit(10).get();
    return snapshot.docs
        .map((docSnapshot) => EntryModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(docSnapshot))
        .toList();
  }
```

But how to request the next 10? The problem is that I don't know what to put in startAfter. I mean the following:

```dart
// Retrieve next 10 entries
  Future<List<EntryModel>> retrieveEntryDataNext(String userDiary) async {
    QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot =
      await _db.collection(userDiary).orderBy("date").startAfter([???]).limit(10).get();
    return snapshot.docs
        .map((docSnapshot) => EntryModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(docSnapshot))
        .toList();
  }
```

Comment: The documentation indicates that `startAfter` is about document content, for document pagination you should use `startAfterDocument`, which is the last document fetching in your list, as said at the end of this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52513767/flutter-firestore-query-with-startafter).